# The configuration section 'autofac' could not be read

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, autofac

We use unit test to test a component which is using `Autofac` to inject all the dependencies and instanciate objects. We use auto section in the configue file for the configuration. The `MSTest` runs very well within `Visual Studio` and through command line.

However, after we put the unit test to run through the `MSTestRunner` plugin within `Jenkins` for continutes build purpose, the following exception is through out:

> "System.ArgumentException: The configuration section 'autofac' could not be read. at Autofac.Configuration.ConfigurationSettingsReader..ctor(String sectionName) "

This is a [similar issues raised](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=247) before and replied as have been fixed already.

The `autofac` version we are using is `2.6.3.862`.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information? Perhaps the stacktrace?